# non blocking thread-safe file write

Tags: multithreading, file-io, nonblocking

I am trying to write in a file at different offset locations using threads that shouldn't get blocked. I am not very sure how to proceed with the same. I am guessing that I need to open the file with O_NONBLOCK flag.

Is it just that I need to open the file with O_NONBLOCK flag and writing process would be the same ?

Any sample piece of code would be helpful as an explanation

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify what language you want to use.

Comment: I am working on a project that demands good performance, that's why want to write to a file using multiple threads simultaneously. It's written in C

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX/Linux [file descriptors associated with files are always ready for read and write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html). In other words, `O_NONBLOCK` has no effect on regular files.

Normally, writing to a file just copies the data to the kernel page cache and returns. Unless the file was opened with `O_DIRECT` flag, or the kernel page cache has too many dirty pages in which case the write becomes blocking.

If you need to do non-blocking writes into a file either create a dedicated thread that does all the writing, or use [asynchronous I/O](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/aio_write.html).

Comment: I got your point but not very clear on how to implement it. I tried doing something but it doesn't work and I feel that something is missing in my code.
Could you please give me an example code or post some standard API's that can be used so that I am able to do asynchronous I/O without doing any harm to the integrity of the data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: IMO the simplest would be to start with [aio_write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/aio_write.html).